# nodeValue return null

Tags: javascript, xml

I am loading xml file and nodeValue function is returning undefined but i dont know why. Here s my [XML file](http://147.175.98.86/~xkranec/xml/shikaku.xml).

```js
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState===4 && this.status===200){
        loadXML(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET","XML/shikaku.xml",true);
xhttp.send();

function loadXML(xml){
    var xmlDoc= xml.responseXML;

    var helpArray=[];
    var width,height;

    width=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("games")[0].getElementsByTagName("game")[0].getElementsByTagName("playground")[0].getElementsByTagName("width")[0].nodeValue;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="helpik.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need put `childNodes[0]` because you have a node TEXT

```
width=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("width")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```